# Updating Indexes without stopping mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have an application with mongodb integrated with it. I need to update an index on a collection in the mongodb, and am thinking of doing it using the mongodb shell using the ensureIndex() command. I just wanted to know the consequences (if there are any) of updating an index on a live database integrated with a live application. Would it corrupt the database and in turn the application. Please let me know about it.

Thanks.

Comment: It will neither corrupt data base or application but it may slow down your mongod. Is the collection which you are going to index huge?

Comment: thanks Lalit for the info

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it won't corrupt the database. But creating an index on a very large collection can take a while and by default it will lock the whole database while the index is being built. To avoid this, you can [create an index in background](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-creation/#index-creation-background) with the `{background: true}` option. While an index is created in background, the database can operate as normal. The index won't get used until building has finished.